# Placing elements around svg : the correct method?

Tags: css, svg

I like to use a lot of svg to illustrate my websites but I struggle everytime on how to place things around it...
I use `position:absolute;` because, it's not very efficient with the responsive.
I'd like to know: how do you place elements "smartly"?

I'm still a student and i'd like to improve the way I code.
Thanks!

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and add it to the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can position SVG the same way as other elements:

[CSS Documentaion: `position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Take a look at the flexbox:

[CSS Documentation: `flexible boxes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

Comment: It's not about the svg but especially text bloc
Like here : https://puu.sh/toeLE/d91a8694f8.png
If you had to put text above/below those lines, how would you proceed ?

Comment: If your question is "how would you proceed?", I would include it in the SVG itself. :)

Comment: Mhh but what about the SEO ?

Comment: In case that the text itself does not get indexed, you can put it in the alt attribute, but actually this is a different question.